# What is the type of ablaut?

Tags: slavic-languages

PS *k**y**snǫti / *k**va**sъ PIE ū / wā (wō)
PS *x**y**titi / *x**va**tati PIE ū / wā (wō)
PS  *x**y**rěti / *х**vо**rati ū / wo
? PS  *t**y** / *t**vо**jь ū / wo

Is it somehow related to kʷetwóres rule?

modern Russian spelling
киснуть / квас
похитить / хватать
хиреть / хворать
ты / твой

[image]
[image]

Note:
PS *y is Old Slavic ЪI (which is a ligature of Ъ followed by I)
PS *Ъ from PIE semivowel u

Comment: Doesn't the Proto-Slavic _*a_ come from PIE long vowels (like PIE _*ā, *ō, *ē_), not from the PIE short _*a_ as you have it in the _«PIE ū / wa»_?

Comment: @Yellow Sky I answered You are right Thank you. Who deleted my answer?

Comment: At face value (I’m not great with Slavic, never have been), _ū/wā_ looks like it would be PIE _*-uh2/*-u̯eh2_, zero- and full-grade forms of a feminine _u_-stem. The personal pronoun forms aren’t regular in PIE either – it’s not even certain whether the nominative was _*tu_, _*tū_ or _*tuh2_ (some have even argued that the base vowel was _*i_). It’s fairly well agreed-upon, though, that the vowel in the strong case forms acted much like a thematic vowel, so the dative was something like _*t(u̯)oi̯_. Wiktionary has a decent overview of some of the suggested reconstructions (under _*túh2_).